# Problems compiling Library

Tags: c, makefile

I am having some difficulties compiling some files that I downloaded (for academic purposes). 
I ran the following command :

```
cd tmp/Detri_2.6.a/detri
```

then
    make detri_new CC=gcc
To build a library from the relevant files and folders extracted to /tmp.

The output is as follows:

```
tmp/Detri_2.6.a/detri$ make detri_new CC=gcc
g++     Makefile.cpp   -o Makefile

Makefile.cpp:16:25: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token
Makefile.cpp:16:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token
Makefile.cpp:17:1: error: ‘LIBS’ does not name a type
Makefile.cpp:20:1: error: ‘MODULES’ does not name a type
[..]
Makefile.cpp:65:73: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token
Makefile.cpp:68:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
Makefile.cpp:68:19: error: ‘$’ does not name a type
Makefile.cpp:68:60: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token
Makefile.cpp:71:10: error: ‘$’ does not name a type
Makefile.cpp:71:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token
Makefile.cpp:71:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘--’ token
Makefile.cpp:71:43: error: ‘$’ does not name a type
make: *** [Makefile] Error 1
```

>

I haven't written the makefile.cpp (please bear in mind this is my  first week of using ubuntu and doing this sort of thing) but previously, the compiler would attempt to build and find an error in the makefile.tmp, not in the .cpp file. Now as the output shows, it isn't going past the point of trying to read the .cpp file.

I am a bit lost here...

Thank you

UPDATE: I have tried what was suggested in the comment below, i.e. running :
    make -k TMPMK=Makefile.tmp  detri_new CC=gcc

Yet I still have the same (window full of) output errors, plus some new ones.

If this is of any help, the code was obtained from the following [website](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/software/cglist/GeomDir/#DETRI)

EDIT: Shortened error output section and clearer explanation of the problem.

Here is the makefile :

```
/* detri/Makefile.cpp --- C pre-processor Makefile for detri. */

/* USAGE: cpp -P ${CPPMK} > ${TMPMK}; make -k TMPMK=${TMPMK} -f ${TMPMK} ... */

/* Targets.  (CHANGE THIS ACCORDING TO YOUR NEEDS!) */
DEST=    ../bin
LIB=     ../lib
INCLUDE= ../include

/* Paramters: DEPEND, SHELL, CC, CPP, CPPMK, TMPMK, COPT. */
/* System specifics: CCFLAGS, AR, RANLIB, MALLOC. */
#include "Makefile.sys"

/* Other libraries. */
INCLS= -I${INCLUDE}
LIBRARIES= -l_sos${DBX} -l_lia${DBX} -l_basic${DBX}
LIBS= -L${LIB}

/* Source and object files. */
MODULES= detri.c delaunay.c flip.c prep.c \
         dt.c print_dt.c search.c trist.c peel.c
H_FILES= detri.h dt.h trist.h
OBJECTS= ${MODULES:.c=.o}

/* Interface. */
normal: detri;  @echo "Detri ready."
debug:  ;       ${MAKE} -k -f ${TMPMK} detri COPT="-D__DEBUG__" DBX=-g
remove: ;       rm -f ${OBJECTS}
all:    normal;

/* BEGIN Meta Interface: make detri_new */
/* Note: This is here so that we can package Detri stand-alone,
   without the alpha shape software and it's top-level Makefile. */

BASIC= ../basic
LIA=   ../lia
SOS=   ../sos
DETRI= ./

HD=echo "\n\n*** X ***\n"
MK= ${MAKE} -k CC="${CC}" CPP="${CPP}" COPT="${COPT}"

detri_new:;   ${MK} check soslibs_           detri_
detri_debug:; ${MK} check soslibs_d          detri_d
detri_all:;   ${MK} check soslibs_d soslibs_ detri_
soslibs_:  basic_ lia_ sos_
detri_:;  @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=Detri}; cd ${DETRI}; ${MK} new'
sos_:;    @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=SoS};   cd ${SOS};   ${MK} new'
lia_:;    @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=Lia};   cd ${LIA};   ${MK} new'
basic_:;  @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=Basic}; cd ${BASIC}; ${MK} new'
soslibs_d: basic_d lia_d sos_d
detri_d:; @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=Detri}; cd ${DETRI}; ${MK} clear debug'
sos_d:;   @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=SoS};   cd ${SOS};   ${MK} clear debug'
lia_d:;   @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=Lia};   cd ${LIA};   ${MK} clear debug'
basic_d:; @/bin/csh -cf '${HD:X=Basic}; cd ${BASIC}; ${MK} clear debug'
check:;   @/bin/csh -cf '           \
  echo Checking for target dirs;     \
  if (! -e ${DEST})    mkdir ${DEST}; \
  if (! -e ${LIB})     mkdir ${LIB};   \
  if (! -e ${INCLUDE}) mkdir ${INCLUDE} \
'

/* Internal rules. */
detri: ${OBJECTS}; ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${DBX} ${COPT} ${OBJECTS} \
                        -o ${DEST}/detri ${LIBS} ${LIBRARIES} ${MALLOC} -lm;

/* Generic rule to compile source files. */
.c.o: ${H_FILES}; ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${DBX} ${COPT} ${INCLS} -c $*.c -o $*.o

/* To compute dependencies with "make depend" ... */
depend:; ${DEPEND} -f${TMPMK} -- ${INCLS} ${MODULES}
```

Comment: Change the extension of `Makefile.cpp` to sth. else, anything not .cpp, .cc, .c or .h would work, as make is trying to compile Makefile.cpp, which is apparently not a C++ file.

Comment: Hi, I just changed the .cpp to.txt and it appears that the compiler starts. However out of 3 runs now, one of them just exited normally suggesting that eveything went to plan: an executable should be generated in /bin (but it wasn't) and the two other runs I did just crashed my computer deleting the folder in question!
Am I doing this wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Edit: Misread "to sth. else, anything not .cpp, .cc, .c or .h would work, ". So tried all three .c .cc .h extensions, non of which work. 
I even tried generating the .tmp file using the `cpp -p` command and the various extensions (h,c and cc) and running the `make -k TMPMK=Makefile.tmp detri_new CC=gcc`
All in all, I am back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, this Makefile.cpp is used to generate Makfeile using C preprocessor. As you can see in Makefile.cpp there is a line:

```
/* USAGE: cpp -P ${CPPMK} > ${TMPMK}; make -k TMPMK=${TMPMK} -f ${TMPMK} ... */
```

This means that you should run C preprocessor (cpp) to get real Makefile. By typing `cpp -P Makefile.cpp > Makefile.tmp` you will generate `Makefile.tmp` based on `Makefile.cpp`. According to this usage comment, you should pass this generated `Makefile.tmp` to make as value for `TMPMK` variable, e.g. `make -k TMPMK=Makefile.tmp detri_new CC=gcc`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have typed the cpp command, however there was already a makefile.tmp included in the package. (Which was somewhat similar to the .cpp file). Either way, I still get more or less the same error, multiplied by the number of different libraries it is tying to compile (3 I believe). The output is too big for me to add here, but ends with the following new errors
'make[6]: Failed to remake makefile `Makefile'.
make[6]: `Makefile.tmp' is up to date.
Makefile.tmp:33: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop.
make: *** [detri_new] Error 2'

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that good with makefiles. But this: Makefile.tmp:33: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?) looks like that spaces were used instead of TAB characters (there are places in Makefile where only TAB must be used). Check that line 33 in tmp file, and try replacing spaces with TAB. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Yes at first, I never got the errors with the .cpp makefile, only with the supplied .tmp (as opposed to the generated .tmp with your command) So I though of fixing the spaces manually only to find that as I would re run the commands, the .tmp file would update (even when I have it open in gedit) back to its original state. This i though could be fixed by modifying the .cpp file to have the right spaces and tabs, and then everything just went crazy.
Even if remove the directory, and restart from scratch, I cant replicate the first set of errors...
Edit: Forgot the magic words... Thank you